# jQuery mega dropbox menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently working on mega dropbox menu. My firt idea was to use LIs as a menu and then somewhere define DIVs for content of megamenu:

```
<ul>
    <li class="menu" id="test_menu">Test</li>
</ul>

<div id="test_supermenu">
  <!-- Content here -->
</div>
```

And this jQuery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("li.menu").hover(function() {
    jQuery("#test_supermenu").position({
      my: "center",
      at: "bottom",
      of: "#test_menu"
    });
    jQuery("#test_supermenu).show();
  }, function() {
    jQuery("#test_supermenu).hide();
  });
});
```

The problem is that when you leave the LI and try to select something in DIV supermenu, the supermenu get hidden. It is expectable, but how can I avoid it?

The second idea was to design the menu and supermenu in one big DIV:

```
<div id="menu">
   <a href="">Test</a>
   <div id="supermenu">
     <! -- Content here -->
   </div>
</div>
```

But the problem is still there.

Could you please give me a suggestion how to solve this problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: Try using "mouseenter" & "mouseleave" events instead of "hover".
"mouseenter" - show. "mouseleave" - check if not over div.

Comment: On a second thought... why not put "#supermenu" inside the "li" element?

Comment: @mishik - Will check you second idea.

Comment: I am currently trying to do it just with CSS and HTML. Without using Javascript. Everything works fine. But when I select one LI, it is maximalized at the expense of the others LI... Do not someone know why?


There is the source code: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qwwyx/) The second LI is not visible cause of width of menu.